# Selection pressures acting on the Goliath from 'Evolve?'

Tags: biology, evolution, xenobiology, behaviour

[image]

I know someone's already asked wether this thing was feasible, but I had a slightly different question: I wanted to know what kinds of things could drive something to... well 'evolve' the way the Goliath has. Turtle Rock clearly drew inspiration from a male gorilla designing it, with the muscular-skeletal structure they went with for most of the body and the color change with age to mark reproductive success; and the gorilla's size and physical strength is largely a result of extremely high mating competition stemming from their single-male, multiple-female social structure, but beyond that- What else does the creature's body structure say, about the way it lives, what/how it eats, what environment it initially developed in, and etc.? I don't particularly care how the game portrays them, I just want to know what we can see in its physiology.

(I know the thing's height is crazy, let's not get into that. Pretend it only gets up to 2 meters at most or however small it has to be for you to believe it could exist on earth.)

(I am particularly curious where this thing might have first adapted before spreading to different environments.)

(The fire breath I'm okay with people ignoring in favor of basing our theories on the biology we can fully understand.)

(I personally think the fire-breath pretty well explains the tiny gut size (this thing cooks its food), and thus part of it's survival with the hips of a biped, but have questions there like 'how small are the things born/how much parental care do these things receive,' and 'how smart/communicative/cooperative do these things have to be to reach adulthood?')

Comment: The Goliath from Evolve isn't biologically viable, so it's not possible to give the evolutionary pressures that caused it to exist.

Comment: Also I don't know if this counts as spoilers but the Goliath didn't naturally evolve, it was designed. A big part of the plot from *Evolve* is that the monsters are *not* natural and large parts of their anatomy down to their genetic material don't occur in nature (even in the context of *Evolve* where planets with alien life exist). They aren't even escaped bioweapons that have gone feral like xenomorphs, they don't have a "natural ecology" given their origins.

Comment: I know there's lore in the game and elsewhere to look at for all kinds of information the devs have written, I don't particularly care about any of it. This creature in particular struck me as the most grounded 'monster' that I've liked the design of, and I'm really curious what people can point to for ideas on how an organism might come to look like this. ANTHRO 101 awakened an obsession with speculative biology in me I don't think I'm ever going to quell, and I want to hear other people's observations and theories.

Comment: This is a third party intellectual property question.